# Как вывести массив из массива?

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [image] => 1 [_title] => ) [1] => Array ( [image] => 1 [_title] => ) )
```

Как вывести из него элементы `image` в один массив ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто пройтись циклом по массиву и собрать всё в новый, ничего сложного:

```
$array = [
    [
        'image' => 1,
        '_title' => ''
    ],
    [
        'image' => 1,
        '_title' => ''
    ]
];

$images = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    array_push($images, $item['image']);
}

print_r($images);
```

Вывод будет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

буду банален, наверное, но :

```
$images = array_column($data, 'image');
```

Comment: Идеальный ответ

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan не совсем,  ибо данная функция требует `PHP 5.5` и выше.

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется пробежаться по массиву и в цикле взять и сохранять элементы в новый массив следующим способом.

```
$images = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $images[] = $item['image'];
}

print_r($images);
```